# Newly published branch in Github (Remote) is not reflected in the local machine

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I created a GitHub Repo then during first commit I created a main branch. After that I created a new branch named "Dev" in GitHub(Remote) how do I access the branch locally via VsCode? **I want the Dev branch in my local machine**
[image: This is from the GitHub repo]

[image: This is from my local machine]

Comment: You need to **fetch** on your local repo so that it gets the updates from the remote... then you should be able to see the remote branch (then you can do operations like checkout, diff, merge, create a local branch from it etc etc).

Comment: run `git fetch` on your local machine -- from VSCode: open the `[...]` menu next to the top `Source Control` title, and select `Fetch`